# onclick insert in to ms sql database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server

I have asp.net application with JavaScript and I want to save in to ms sql DB additional information(TimeStamp) when a button is clicked.

```
onclick= "functionName();"
```

the function "functionName()" has another task and I want another function that store the timestamp as well

Comment: What's the problem with having two operations in one function? This will also require some simple ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `JS` as below:

```
function functionName() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    var now = new Date(); // You can also any kind of data using query string
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "saveTimespan.aspx?datetime=" + now, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Write below code to code behind of `saveTimespan.aspx' page as below(remove all markup other than`Page` directory of this page):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTimeStamp();
}

public void UpdateTimeStamp()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TargetTable SET DateTimColumnName = @DateTimColumnName";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTimColumnName", MyDateTime);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
        {
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Data Updated Successfully!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery ajax, would be easier like

```
function functionName() {
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
}
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I have javascript events (buttons ) . how can use the above function